# GraphQL Query - cannot see nested elements in JSON respone

Tags: node.js, graphql

if anyone can hazard a guess or where to look it would be greatly appreciated. 
I can get nested data when I run using graphgl API, however, from my node program it only shows top-level items - does not display the nested elements for the customer and lineitem object. 
I am using Koa middle where, with promise response:

```
router.get('/orders/', async (ctx) => {
const auth = prepareAuth(ctx);
await getOrders(auth).then(response => ctx.body = response.data.data.orders);

console.log(ctx.body.edges)
```

However from the console it has (customer null and 'object':

```
[
  {
    node: {
      createdAt: '2020-02-24T12:53:20Z',
      customer: null,
      name: '#1001',
      lineItems: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      createdAt: '2020-02-24T12:53:50Z',
      customer: null,
      name: '#1002',
      lineItems: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      createdAt: '2020-03-10T21:11:04Z',
      customer: null,
      name: '#1003',
      lineItems: [Object]
    }
  }
]
```

when i use the GraphQL API directly the query works fine and I get full response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "orders": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "createdAt": "2020-02-24T12:53:20Z",
            "customer": {
              "displayName": "franko girl"
            },
            "name": "#1001",
            "lineItems": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "name": "dance mat red",
                    "quantity": 4
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "createdAt": "2020-02-24T12:53:50Z",
            "customer": {
              "displayName": "franko man"
            },
            "name": "#1002",
            "lineItems": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "name": "dance mat black",
                    "quantity": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "createdAt": "2020-03-10T21:11:04Z",
            "customer": {
              "displayName": "franko man"
            },
            "name": "#1003",
            "lineItems": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "name": "dance mat black",
                    "quantity": 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "name": "dance mat red",
                    "quantity": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so finally figured this out, for anyone else who stumbles accross this problem, you need to the convert the json object to a string using built in javascript function: JSON.stringify()

from W3schools.com

var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);